# How to solve $\ddot z + Az = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve $$ \ddot z + Az=0 $$
with $A>0$

I assume that $$z=e^{\lambda t} $$
So the equation becomes $$z(\lambda^2+A)=0$$
and so $\lambda_1=i\sqrt A$ and $\lambda_2=-i\sqrt A$
and then $$z=e^{i\sqrt At}+e^{-i\sqrt A t}=2\cos(\sqrt A t)$$

But I'm quite sure I'm actually supposed to find something looking like
$$\alpha\cos(\sqrt At)+\beta\sin(\sqrt At)$$

What have I missed ?

Comment: Is $A$ a positive number, or a positive definite matrix?

Comment: A positive number (this actually is a mechanics problem, $A=k/m$)

Comment: I don't see the problem, your answer is of the right form, it's just that $\beta=0$

Comment: Setting $\lambda_i$ as given satisfies the equation, but your assumption that $z=e^{\lambda t}$ is overly restrictive. Assume instead that $z=k e^{\lambda t}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the correct eigenvalues, but you need to remember that a solution can be a linear combination of solutions:

$z = \eta e^{i \sqrt{A} t} + \gamma e^{-i \sqrt{A} t} $

Using [Euler's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula):

$z = \eta (cos(\sqrt{A}t)+sin(\sqrt{A}t)) + \gamma (cos(\sqrt{A}t)+sin(\sqrt{A}t))    $

then $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are some combo of $\eta$ and $\gamma$

Comment: Thanks, I suppose that $\eta$ and $\gamma \in \mathbb{C}$ here ?

Comment: At the very least, yes, but I assume that they are in $\mathbb{R}$